# Disabling/ignoring the Windows service "Windows Registry"

Tags: vbscript

I have this VBscript, which is fairly simple, however, I'm asking if its possible to add a line of code, that disables the "Windows Registry" service, that usually runs on every windows machine.

```vb
'----------------------------------------------------------------
' Type: Monitor
' Desc: Check to see if ANY services are set to auto start but are not running
' Input:    
' Output:   Output (String)     -   Output message to return
' Alert:    If ANY services meet the criteria
' Author:   Simon McBryde
' Ver:  1.0
'----------------------------------------------------------------

'----------------------------------------------------------------
'   Initialize input variables
'----------------------------------------------------------------

Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )

strAttemptStart = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%AttemptStart%" )

'----------------------------------------------------------------
' Main script logic
'----------------------------------------------------------------

Dim objWMIService, objService, colService, strComputer, strOutput

strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colService = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_Service")

strOutput = ""
strRestart = ""

For Each objService in colService
  If objService.StartMode = "Auto" And objService.State <> "Running" Then
    strOutput = strOutput & objService.DisplayName & " (" &  objService.Name & "), " & "Current state: " & objService.State

    If strAttemptStart = "true" Then
      strResult = objService.StartService()
      Select Case strResult
        Case 0 strOutput = strOutput & ", Restart result: " & "Success"
        Case 1 strOutput = strOutput & ", Restart result: " & "Not Supported"
        Case 2 strOutput = strOutput & ", Restart result: " & "Access Denied"
        Case 3 strOutput = strOutput & ", Restart result: " & "Dependent Services Running"
        Case 4 strOutput = strOutput & ", Restart result: " & "Invalid Service Control"
        Case 5 strOutput = strOutput & ", Restart result: " & "Service Cannot Accept Control"
        Case 6 strOutput = strOutput & ", Restart result: " & "Service Not Active"
        Case 7 strOutput = strOutput & ", Restart result: " & "Service Request Timeout"
        Case 8 strOutput = strOutput & ", Restart result: " & "Unknown Failure"
        Case 9 strOutput = strOutput & ", Restart result: " & "Path Not Found"
        Case 10 strOutput = strOutput & ", Restart result: " & "Service Already Running"
        Case 11 strOutput = strOutput & ", Restart result: " & "Service Database Locked"
        Case 12 strOutput = strOutput & ", Restart result: " & "Service Dependency Deleted"
        Case 13 strOutput = strOutput & ", Restart result: " & "Service Dependency Failure"
        Case 14 strOutput = strOutput & ", Restart result: " & "Service Disabled"
        Case 15 strOutput = strOutput & ", Restart result: " & "Service Logon Failure"
        Case 16 strOutput = strOutput & ", Restart result: " & "Service Marked For Deletion"
        Case 17 strOutput = strOutput & ", Restart result: " & "Service No Thread"
        Case 18 strOutput = strOutput & ", Restart result: " & "Status Circular Dependency"
        Case 19 strOutput = strOutput & ", Restart result: " & "Status Duplicate Name"
        Case 20 strOutput = strOutput & ", Restart result: " & "Status Invalid Name"
        Case 21 strOutput = strOutput & ", Restart result: " & "Status Invalid Parameter"
        Case 22 strOutput = strOutput & ", Restart result: " & "Status Invalid Service Account"
        Case 23 strOutput = strOutput & ", Restart result: " & "Status Service Exists"
        Case 24 strOutput = strOutput & ", Restart result: " & "Service Already Paused"
      End Select
    End If

    strOutput = strOutput & " ***** "
  End If
Next

If strOutput <> "" Then GenerateAlert strOutput, 1

'----------------------------------------------------------------
' Output result and quit with required exit code
'----------------------------------------------------------------

Sub GenerateAlert (strOutput, intExitCode)
  WScript.Echo "<-Start Result->"
  WScript.Echo "Output=" & strOutput
  WScript.Echo "<-End Result->"

  WScript.Quit intExitCode
End Sub
```

Comment: Does not seem related to Java or JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for proposed edit.

Answer (score 0):

Restrict the results of your WQL query if you want to ignore the service:

```
"SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE Name <> 'RemoteRegistry'"
```

Add a condition if you want to stop the service:

```
If strAttemptStart = "true" Then
  If objService.Name = "RemoteRegistry" Then
    strResult = objService.StopService()
  Else
    strResult = objService.StartService()
  End If
  Select Case strResult
    ...
  End Select
End If
```

Comment: Thanks. Helped alot. What if i wanted it to check if the windows service is set to automatic, and if so, i would like to start it. (Sometimes the automatic services are disabled or turned off by default)

Comment: Check the `StartMode` property.

Comment: Great, i made it work. What if i don't  want to monitor, but ignore some specific instances of a windows service? The only research i found, allowed me me to disable a service, but that Isen't what I'm looking for.